# How to run Ruby on Rails on new MacBook Air M1?

Tags: macos, ruby, ruby-on-rails, rails

I am running Ruby version 2.7.2 and I have been trying to run Ruby on Rails but nothing seems to work. I tried `rvm`, `rbenv` and now `asdf` but everytime I try to run `rails server` in an old project after  successfully running `bundle install` I get this long error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    29: from bin/rails:2:in `<main>'
    28: from bin/rails:2:in `load'
    27: from /Users/arpanabhishek/projects/coronafree-projects/todo_manager/bin/spring:7:in `<top (required)>'
    26: from /Users/arpanabhishek/projects/coronafree-projects/todo_manager/bin/spring:7:in `tap'
    25: from /Users/arpanabhishek/projects/coronafree-projects/todo_manager/bin/spring:10:in `block in <top (required)>'
    24: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    23: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    22: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    21: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
    20: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
    19: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
    18: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    17: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
    16: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
    15: from /Users/arpanabhishek/projects/coronafree-projects/todo_manager/bin/rails:4:in `<top (required)>'
    14: from /Users/arpanabhishek/projects/coronafree-projects/todo_manager/bin/rails:4:in `require_relative'
    13: from /Users/arpanabhishek/projects/coronafree-projects/todo_manager/config/boot.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    12: from /Users/arpanabhishek/projects/coronafree-projects/todo_manager/config/boot.rb:4:in `require'
    11: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap/setup.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    10: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap/setup.rb:2:in `require_relative'
     9: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
     8: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap.rb:5:in `require_relative'
     7: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache.rb:74:in `<top (required)>'
     6: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache.rb:74:in `require_relative'
     5: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/store.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
     4: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap/explicit_require.rb:41:in `with_gems'
     3: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/store.rb:4:in `block in <top (required)>'
     2: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/store.rb:4:in `require'
     1: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/msgpack-1.3.3/lib/msgpack.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/msgpack-1.3.3/lib/msgpack.rb:9:in `require': cannot load such file -- msgpack/2.6/msgpack (LoadError)
    30: from bin/rails:2:in `<main>'
    29: from bin/rails:2:in `load'
    28: from /Users/arpanabhishek/projects/coronafree-projects/todo_manager/bin/spring:7:in `<top (required)>'
    27: from /Users/arpanabhishek/projects/coronafree-projects/todo_manager/bin/spring:7:in `tap'
    26: from /Users/arpanabhishek/projects/coronafree-projects/todo_manager/bin/spring:10:in `block in <top (required)>'
    25: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    24: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    23: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    22: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
    21: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
    20: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
    19: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    18: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
    17: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
    16: from /Users/arpanabhishek/projects/coronafree-projects/todo_manager/bin/rails:4:in `<top (required)>'
    15: from /Users/arpanabhishek/projects/coronafree-projects/todo_manager/bin/rails:4:in `require_relative'
    14: from /Users/arpanabhishek/projects/coronafree-projects/todo_manager/config/boot.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    13: from /Users/arpanabhishek/projects/coronafree-projects/todo_manager/config/boot.rb:4:in `require'
    12: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap/setup.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    11: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap/setup.rb:2:in `require_relative'
    10: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
     9: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap.rb:5:in `require_relative'
     8: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache.rb:74:in `<top (required)>'
     7: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache.rb:74:in `require_relative'
     6: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/store.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
     5: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap/explicit_require.rb:41:in `with_gems'
     4: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/store.rb:4:in `block in <top (required)>'
     3: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/store.rb:4:in `require'
     2: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/msgpack-1.3.3/lib/msgpack.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
     1: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/msgpack-1.3.3/lib/msgpack.rb:11:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/msgpack-1.3.3/lib/msgpack.rb:11:in `require': dlopen(/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/msgpack-1.3.3/lib/msgpack/msgpack.bundle, 0x0009): missing compatible arch in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/msgpack-1.3.3/lib/msgpack/msgpack.bundle - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/msgpack-1.3.3/lib/msgpack/msgpack.bundle (LoadError)
    30: from bin/rails:2:in `<main>'
    29: from bin/rails:2:in `load'
    28: from /Users/arpanabhishek/projects/coronafree-projects/todo_manager/bin/spring:7:in `<top (required)>'
    27: from /Users/arpanabhishek/projects/coronafree-projects/todo_manager/bin/spring:7:in `tap'
    26: from /Users/arpanabhishek/projects/coronafree-projects/todo_manager/bin/spring:10:in `block in <top (required)>'
    25: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    24: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    23: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    22: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
    21: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
    20: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
    19: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    18: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
    17: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
    16: from /Users/arpanabhishek/projects/coronafree-projects/todo_manager/bin/rails:4:in `<top (required)>'
    15: from /Users/arpanabhishek/projects/coronafree-projects/todo_manager/bin/rails:4:in `require_relative'
    14: from /Users/arpanabhishek/projects/coronafree-projects/todo_manager/config/boot.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    13: from /Users/arpanabhishek/projects/coronafree-projects/todo_manager/config/boot.rb:4:in `require'
    12: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap/setup.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    11: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap/setup.rb:2:in `require_relative'
    10: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
     9: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap.rb:5:in `require_relative'
     8: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache.rb:74:in `<top (required)>'
     7: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache.rb:74:in `require_relative'
     6: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/store.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
     5: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap/explicit_require.rb:40:in `with_gems'
     4: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap/explicit_require.rb:44:in `rescue in with_gems'
     3: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/store.rb:4:in `block in <top (required)>'
     2: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/store.rb:4:in `require'
     1: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/msgpack-1.3.3/lib/msgpack.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/msgpack-1.3.3/lib/msgpack.rb:9:in `require': cannot load such file -- msgpack/2.6/msgpack (LoadError)
    31: from bin/rails:2:in `<main>'
    30: from bin/rails:2:in `load'
    29: from /Users/arpanabhishek/projects/coronafree-projects/todo_manager/bin/spring:7:in `<top (required)>'
    28: from /Users/arpanabhishek/projects/coronafree-projects/todo_manager/bin/spring:7:in `tap'
    27: from /Users/arpanabhishek/projects/coronafree-projects/todo_manager/bin/spring:10:in `block in <top (required)>'
    26: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    25: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    24: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    23: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
    22: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
    21: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
    20: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    19: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
    18: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
    17: from /Users/arpanabhishek/projects/coronafree-projects/todo_manager/bin/rails:4:in `<top (required)>'
    16: from /Users/arpanabhishek/projects/coronafree-projects/todo_manager/bin/rails:4:in `require_relative'
    15: from /Users/arpanabhishek/projects/coronafree-projects/todo_manager/config/boot.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    14: from /Users/arpanabhishek/projects/coronafree-projects/todo_manager/config/boot.rb:4:in `require'
    13: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap/setup.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    12: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap/setup.rb:2:in `require_relative'
    11: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    10: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap.rb:5:in `require_relative'
     9: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache.rb:74:in `<top (required)>'
     8: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache.rb:74:in `require_relative'
     7: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/store.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
     6: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap/explicit_require.rb:40:in `with_gems'
     5: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap/explicit_require.rb:44:in `rescue in with_gems'
     4: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/store.rb:4:in `block in <top (required)>'
     3: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/store.rb:4:in `require'
     2: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/msgpack-1.3.3/lib/msgpack.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
     1: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/msgpack-1.3.3/lib/msgpack.rb:11:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/msgpack-1.3.3/lib/msgpack.rb:11:in `require': dlopen(/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/msgpack-1.3.3/lib/msgpack/msgpack.bundle, 0x0009): missing compatible arch in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/msgpack-1.3.3/lib/msgpack/msgpack.bundle - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/msgpack-1.3.3/lib/msgpack/msgpack.bundle (LoadError)
```

If I try to create new rails app I get this error

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    29: from bin/rails:2:in `<main>'
    28: from bin/rails:2:in `load'
    27: from /Users/arpanabhishek/projects/coronafree-projects/myApp/bin/spring:7:in `<top (required)>'
    26: from /Users/arpanabhishek/projects/coronafree-projects/myApp/bin/spring:7:in `tap'
    25: from /Users/arpanabhishek/projects/coronafree-projects/myApp/bin/spring:10:in `block in <top (required)>'
    24: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    23: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    22: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    21: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
    20: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
    19: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
    18: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    17: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
    16: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
    15: from /Users/arpanabhishek/projects/coronafree-projects/myApp/bin/rails:4:in `<top (required)>'
    14: from /Users/arpanabhishek/projects/coronafree-projects/myApp/bin/rails:4:in `require_relative'
    13: from /Users/arpanabhishek/projects/coronafree-projects/myApp/config/boot.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    12: from /Users/arpanabhishek/projects/coronafree-projects/myApp/config/boot.rb:4:in `require'
    11: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap/setup.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    10: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap/setup.rb:2:in `require_relative'
     9: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
     8: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap.rb:5:in `require_relative'
     7: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache.rb:74:in `<top (required)>'
     6: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache.rb:74:in `require_relative'
     5: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/store.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
     4: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap/explicit_require.rb:41:in `with_gems'
     3: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/store.rb:4:in `block in <top (required)>'
     2: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/store.rb:4:in `require'
     1: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/msgpack-1.3.3/lib/msgpack.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/msgpack-1.3.3/lib/msgpack.rb:9:in `require': cannot load such file -- msgpack/2.6/msgpack (LoadError)
    30: from bin/rails:2:in `<main>'
    29: from bin/rails:2:in `load'
    28: from /Users/arpanabhishek/projects/coronafree-projects/myApp/bin/spring:7:in `<top (required)>'
    27: from /Users/arpanabhishek/projects/coronafree-projects/myApp/bin/spring:7:in `tap'
    26: from /Users/arpanabhishek/projects/coronafree-projects/myApp/bin/spring:10:in `block in <top (required)>'
    25: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    24: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    23: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    22: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
    21: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
    20: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
    19: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    18: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
    17: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
    16: from /Users/arpanabhishek/projects/coronafree-projects/myApp/bin/rails:4:in `<top (required)>'
    15: from /Users/arpanabhishek/projects/coronafree-projects/myApp/bin/rails:4:in `require_relative'
    14: from /Users/arpanabhishek/projects/coronafree-projects/myApp/config/boot.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    13: from /Users/arpanabhishek/projects/coronafree-projects/myApp/config/boot.rb:4:in `require'
    12: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap/setup.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    11: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap/setup.rb:2:in `require_relative'
    10: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
     9: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap.rb:5:in `require_relative'
     8: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache.rb:74:in `<top (required)>'
     7: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache.rb:74:in `require_relative'
     6: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/store.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
     5: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap/explicit_require.rb:41:in `with_gems'
     4: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/store.rb:4:in `block in <top (required)>'
     3: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/store.rb:4:in `require'
     2: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/msgpack-1.3.3/lib/msgpack.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
     1: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/msgpack-1.3.3/lib/msgpack.rb:11:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/msgpack-1.3.3/lib/msgpack.rb:11:in `require': dlsym(0x7fe15f3a38d0, Init_msgpack): symbol not found - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/msgpack-1.3.3/lib/msgpack/msgpack.bundle (LoadError)
    30: from bin/rails:2:in `<main>'
    29: from bin/rails:2:in `load'
    28: from /Users/arpanabhishek/projects/coronafree-projects/myApp/bin/spring:7:in `<top (required)>'
    27: from /Users/arpanabhishek/projects/coronafree-projects/myApp/bin/spring:7:in `tap'
    26: from /Users/arpanabhishek/projects/coronafree-projects/myApp/bin/spring:10:in `block in <top (required)>'
    25: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    24: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    23: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    22: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
    21: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
    20: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
    19: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    18: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
    17: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
    16: from /Users/arpanabhishek/projects/coronafree-projects/myApp/bin/rails:4:in `<top (required)>'
    15: from /Users/arpanabhishek/projects/coronafree-projects/myApp/bin/rails:4:in `require_relative'
    14: from /Users/arpanabhishek/projects/coronafree-projects/myApp/config/boot.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    13: from /Users/arpanabhishek/projects/coronafree-projects/myApp/config/boot.rb:4:in `require'
    12: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap/setup.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    11: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap/setup.rb:2:in `require_relative'
    10: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
     9: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap.rb:5:in `require_relative'
     8: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache.rb:74:in `<top (required)>'
     7: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache.rb:74:in `require_relative'
     6: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/store.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
     5: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap/explicit_require.rb:40:in `with_gems'
     4: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap/explicit_require.rb:44:in `rescue in with_gems'
     3: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/store.rb:4:in `block in <top (required)>'
     2: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/store.rb:4:in `require'
     1: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/msgpack-1.3.3/lib/msgpack.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/msgpack-1.3.3/lib/msgpack.rb:9:in `require': cannot load such file -- msgpack/2.6/msgpack (LoadError)
    31: from bin/rails:2:in `<main>'
    30: from bin/rails:2:in `load'
    29: from /Users/arpanabhishek/projects/coronafree-projects/myApp/bin/spring:7:in `<top (required)>'
    28: from /Users/arpanabhishek/projects/coronafree-projects/myApp/bin/spring:7:in `tap'
    27: from /Users/arpanabhishek/projects/coronafree-projects/myApp/bin/spring:10:in `block in <top (required)>'
    26: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    25: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    24: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    23: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
    22: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
    21: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
    20: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    19: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
    18: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
    17: from /Users/arpanabhishek/projects/coronafree-projects/myApp/bin/rails:4:in `<top (required)>'
    16: from /Users/arpanabhishek/projects/coronafree-projects/myApp/bin/rails:4:in `require_relative'
    15: from /Users/arpanabhishek/projects/coronafree-projects/myApp/config/boot.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    14: from /Users/arpanabhishek/projects/coronafree-projects/myApp/config/boot.rb:4:in `require'
    13: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap/setup.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    12: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap/setup.rb:2:in `require_relative'
    11: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    10: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap.rb:5:in `require_relative'
     9: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache.rb:74:in `<top (required)>'
     8: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache.rb:74:in `require_relative'
     7: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/store.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
     6: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap/explicit_require.rb:40:in `with_gems'
     5: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap/explicit_require.rb:44:in `rescue in with_gems'
     4: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/store.rb:4:in `block in <top (required)>'
     3: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/store.rb:4:in `require'
     2: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/msgpack-1.3.3/lib/msgpack.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
     1: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/msgpack-1.3.3/lib/msgpack.rb:11:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/msgpack-1.3.3/lib/msgpack.rb:11:in `require': dlsym(0x7fe15f2d35c0, Init_msgpack): symbol not found - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/msgpack-1.3.3/lib/msgpack/msgpack.bundle (LoadError)
```

Comment: I'm not a Ruby/Rails expert, but it seems to be saying that one of your Ruby gems, msgpack, doesn't have a precompiled binary for the right architecture. So perhaps you're running an Apple Silicon (ARM) version of  the Ruby interpreter, but your msgpack.bundle is perhaps still an old Intel x86_64 version (or vice-versa). macOS, even with Rosetta 2, doesn't support mixing architectures in the same process space. The solution would be to install a build of msgpack that's been built for the right architecture.

Comment: As per what @Spiff says the most likely reason you have to reinstall your Ruby Gems and such. M1 (ARM) architecture is 100% different than Intel architecture. And when it comes to command line apps and tools that are custom to your setup, you need to consider reinstalling items from scratch. That is probably the main/overriding issue you are facing.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just got stuck on the problem for a whole day on my new M1.

Solved it by:

1. Go find terminal in Finder under applications/utilities. <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> then <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd> "terminal" and rename it to "TerminalRosetta"
2. Right click and then click "get info". Then check the box that says "Open using Rosetta". Then hit the red x and close that dialog.
3. Open and use "TerminalRosetta" from now on
4. paste:    `export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"`   into your terminal and hit enter
5. paste:   `eval "$(rbenv init -)"`   into your terminal and hit enter
6. Install ruby and rails as usual.

If you have any other problems-- i used this tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jT_SPPPhRBk

Comment: It should be noted that this solution chooses to use Rosetta 2 instead of native code, which means it could be slower and less power-efficient. That might be the easiest workaround for now, but a solution that allows Ruby, Rails, msgpack, and all other Ruby Gems to run native code would be preferable to this.

Comment: Really Realy thx!
I was trying it so hard for my new job; I'm new to MacOS enviroment. And finally, we reinstall MacOS from zero and follow this steps and worked.
One beer for you!

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue and found you can achieve a native (non-Rosetta) solution by

1. install [Homebrew](https://brew.sh)
2. `brew install ruby` (currently 3.0.1) - this enables rbenv to succeed in building other versions where Apple's system ruby causes failures
3. `brew install rbenv`, then set up your shell
4. homebrew's ruby is keg-only, so you need to `export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/ruby/lib/pkgconfig"` before you:
5. `rbenv install 2.7.3` - I did not have success on lower versions
6. `bundle install`
7. if using older `Gemfile.lock` you might need to wrangle gem versions - I had to update some to get my app working